# SSRS Remove xml header from SOAP message

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have created an SSRS report that connects to a third party web service. I am trying to then flatten out that xml using the ElementPathNode.

My xml is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap>
<GetAllCustomersResponse>
<GetAllCustomersResult>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Customers>
        <Customer id="1">
            <Entry>
                <FromTime>2016-07-31T04:00:00</FromTime>
                <ToTime>2016-08-01T04:00:00</ToTime>
            </Entry>
            <Entry>
                <FromTime>2016-08-01T04:00:00</FromTime>
                <ToTime>2016-08-02T04:00:00</ToTime>
            </Entry>
        </Customer>
    </Customers>
</GetAllCustomersResult>
</GetAllCustomersResponse>
</soap>
```

So this is invalid xml because the webs service that returns the data is inserting the xml declaration and then this is wrapped in the soap message. I then don't think I can select the data properly e.g.

```
<ElementPath>GetAllCustomersResponse/GetAllCustomersResult/Customers/Customer/Entry{FromTime,ToTime}</ElementPath>
```

Any ideas how i could ignore/strip out this unwanted declaration?